# How do I update/set a long list of data To Firestore - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, This feature is for a user to make their online profile and allow them to edit their information (eg. name, bio, company, position, etc). I am aware that I can just use update/set JSON according to the flutterfire documentation but what if I have a lot of these fields that the user can edit and update.

P.S. just an example of 1 section (user's experience/occupation)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final pcx = Get.find<ProfileController>();

return Column(
  children: [
    SizedBox(height: 20),
    ProfileField(
      controller: pcx.experienceTC,
      title: 'Section Title',
      hintText: 'e.g What I do',
      maxLength: 20,
    ),
    ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: value,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('Experience ${index + 1}'),
              Divider(
                color: MyColor.black,
                indent: 20,
                endIndent: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ProfileField(
                title: 'Position',
              ),
              ProfileField(
                title: 'Company Name',
              ),
              ProfileField(
                title: 'Company Mobile',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              ),
              ProfileField(
                title: 'Company Website',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
              ),
              ProfileField(
                title: 'Company Address',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
            ],
          );
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can create document for every user so every user can only update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).